# specifying which adapter wininet will use

Tags: c++, wininet

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application that uses WinInet to retrieve files from HTTP and FTP servers. Is there a way I can specify which network adapter WinInet will use to connect to the remote servers or specify which IP address will originate the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the short answer is that you cannot. WinInet doesn't expose most of the lower-level (Winsock) functionality that you'd need to accomplish this.

I know that Winsock does allow more control over the network interfaces/adapters, but then you'd have to decide on a way to make the HTTP/FTP requests beyond that.